# How to make nested for-loop do every permutation

Tags: r, for-loop

Basic question, but unsure how to resolve based on other posts that use vectors of characters or other situations that don't fully enlighten my own simple problem.

I want to make a nested for loop to calculate all possible combinations of two equations (`x` and `y`) along two vectors, and store every single calculation.

Here is my code:

```
n_c = 1
m_c = 1
n_n = 1
m_n = 1
my_data_c = c()
my_data_n = c()
rho_c_store = c()
rho_n_store = c()

for(i in 1:10){
  for(j in 1:10){
    rho_c = i / 10
    rho_n = j / 10
    
    x = (rho_c*n_c)/m_c
    y = (rho_n*n_n)/m_n
    
    rho_c_store[i] = rho_c
    rho_n_store[j] = rho_n
    
    my_data_c[i] = x
    my_data_n[j] = y
    
    my_data = cbind(rho_c_store,rho_n_store,my_data_c,my_data_n)
  }
}
print(my_data)
```

The output I get is:

```
> print(my_data)
      rho_c_store rho_n_store my_data_c my_data_n
 [1,]         0.1         0.1       0.1       0.1
 [2,]         0.2         0.2       0.2       0.2
 [3,]         0.3         0.3       0.3       0.3
 [4,]         0.4         0.4       0.4       0.4
 [5,]         0.5         0.5       0.5       0.5
 [6,]         0.6         0.6       0.6       0.6
 [7,]         0.7         0.7       0.7       0.7
 [8,]         0.8         0.8       0.8       0.8
 [9,]         0.9         0.9       0.9       0.9
[10,]         1.0         1.0       1.0       1.0
```

However, the data I **want** is:

```
> print(my_data)
      rho_c_store rho_n_store my_data_c my_data_n
 [1,]         0.1         0.1       ?        ?
 [2,]         0.1         0.2       ?        ?
 [3,]         0.1         0.3       ?        ?
 [4,]         0.1         0.4       ?        ?
 [5,]         0.1         0.5       ?        ?
 [6,]         0.1         0.6       ?        ?
 [7,]         0.1         0.7       ?        ?
 [8,]         0.1         0.8       ?        ?
 [9,]         0.1         0.9       ?        ?
[10,]         0.1         1.0       ?        ?
[11,]         0.2         0.1       ?        ?
[12,]         0.2         0.2       ?        ?
[13,]         0.2         0.3       ?        ?
[14,]         0.2         0.4       ?        ?
[15,]         0.2         0.5       ?        ?

... etc
```

I know I could solve this in some way with grid.expand() and an apply() function (trying to figure that out in parallel), but I'm annoyed at my inability to solve this basic code setup.

Thanks!

Comment: you are overwriting the same elements each time through the loop. You should ncrement the row number each time and store everything in a new row.  Also best to initialise mydata at the required size

Comment: @dww thanks, I assume that means indexing something as `[i+1]` and `[j+1]` at some point in the loop? I'm not quite sure what the best way to store a number at a certain row is and then increase the row number for the next calculation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others have pointed out you overwrite your elements again and again - you do not actually assign to the row that you mean to. I've included the code that explicitly calculates the index - maybe this is clearer to you. I've also made a few corrections (e.g. you can take the final construction out of the loop).

```
n_c <- 1 # generally: use <- for assignment
m_c <- 1
n_n <- 1
m_n <- 1
my_data_c <- c() # better: pre-allocate as vector("numeric", 100)
my_data_n <- c()
rho_c_store <- c()
rho_n_store <- c()

for (i in 1:10) {
  # you can move this assignment to the outer loop
  rho_c <- i / 10
  x <- (rho_c * n_c)/m_c

  for (j in 1:10) {
    rho_n <- j / 10
    y <- (rho_n * n_n)/m_n

    index <- 10*(i-1) + j
    rho_c_store[index] <- rho_c
    rho_n_store[index] <- rho_n

    my_data_c[index] <- x
    my_data_n[index] <- y
  }
}

# cbind should be outside the for loop, you only want to build the final
# matrix once you've completed building the vectors
my_data <- cbind(rho_c_store, rho_n_store, my_data_c, my_data_n)

print(my_data)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is a great explanation thank you. I appreciate the extra comments as well, to improve my coding intuition!

Comment: I think I'm missing understanding on how to set up the index still. I am now trying to set this up, but with three sex of indices (and really, I want to set this up so I understand how to do it with any # of them). The code below doesn't exactly work, the third loop calculations don't work.

Ah oops, I have to make a new question since it's too long...

Comment: here is the second question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73857128/part-2-how-to-make-nested-for-loop-do-every-permutation

I know it's painful, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you store the variables at the wrong place. In other words when you loop through the second for-loop your `i` has always the same value. So you store each result of `x` on the same place. That's why you have to create an index which goes from 1:100 (in your case), and not from 1:10 only.
Hope you understand what I mean.

If I take your code with with some corrections it should look like this

```
n_c = 1
m_c = 1
n_n = 1
m_n = 1
my_data_c = c()
my_data_n = c()
rho_c_store = c()
rho_n_store = c()

iter = 10

for(i in 1:iter){
  sequence = seq(i*iter-iter+1,i*iter)
  for(j in 1:iter){
    index = sequence[j]
    
    rho_c = i / 10
    rho_n = j / 10
    
    x = (rho_c*n_c)/m_c
    y = (rho_n*n_n)/m_n
    
    rho_c_store[index] = rho_c
    rho_n_store[index] = rho_n
    
    my_data_c[index] = x
    my_data_n[index] = y
    
    my_data = cbind(rho_c_store,rho_n_store,my_data_c,my_data_n)
  }
}
print(my_data)
```

In my example my seqence is an altering index which goes from 1 to 10 when `i` = 1 and then from 11 to 20 and so on.

I hope this is what you meant.

Comment: Ahhhh yes this totally makes sense. Thank you so much!